# How do I implement scrolling for a Custom Control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+, gdi

How do I implement scrolling for my Custom Control? My control is fully custom drawn and its height is variable, and a part of the control contains a menu so if there are many items in the control, I'll need to be able to put scroll bars there. I've not really been able to find any clues on how to do this. I did see something about `ScrollableControl`, but I'm still not sure if that's what I need.

Also, how will my control know when it needs to show the scroll bars? Because my control is fully custom drawn so there's no real "controls" in there it's just a bunch of pixels that are drawn onto it so it's not like I can just set AutoScroll to true and I can't do that anyway because it's not the main part of the control that needs scrolling, it's a particular location on the control that will need to have the scrollbars.

Answer (score 10):

If your custom control inherits from the Panel control, you just set the size of the content yourself in the custom control by this setting:

```
this.AutoScrollMinSize = New Size(yourWidth, yourHeight);
```

If your control's ClientSize.Height is greater than yourHeight, you won't get any scrollbars.  If it's less, then you get a scrollbar.

In your paint method, add this to the beginning:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
  e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(this.AutoScrollPosition.X,
                                this.AutoScrollPosition.Y);
```

Now everything you paint gets automatically transformed to the scrolling coordinates.

Comment: Thanks but it's not the whole size of the control that needs scrolling, it's only the about a quarter of the control that needs scrollbars. (think of a panel control with a button; you click the button then a scrollable menu pops up) With your solution though, the whole control will scroll, correct?

Comment: @jay_t55 I focused on your statment: `My control is fully custom drawn...`  The part that scrolls needs to have it's own container.

Comment: Have you resolved your problem? If any of the answers were of use you may want to _accept_ it.

Comment: This answers are not of use. Yes, my control is fully custom drawn, however, only PART of the control needs to be scrolled. Think of a webpage with an iframe. You've got a header (div) the body (containing a scrolling iframe) and the footer. The header and footer don't scroll, but the iframe will because it has lots of content.

Comment: @SE13013 Then you create different panels for the header, body and footer and just scroll the footer.  Desktop and Web applications are different beasts.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

The good new is that it is possible and both are not really hard.

- The bad new is that for one option you will have to adapt all your drawing code:

First make your Control, I use a `Panel`, to have `Autoscroll=true;`

Then you need to add one **dummy** control, I use another `Panel`, maybe like this, far enough to the right and bottom to force the `ScrollBars` to show:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Panel panelDummy = new Panel();
    panelDummy.Size = new Size(1,1);
    panelDummy.Location = new Point(yourMaxX,yourMaxY);
    panel1.Controls.Add(panelDummy);
}
```

And then you need to adapt your drawing code. Here is how:

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    int xx = panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value;
    int yy = panel1.VerticalScroll.Value;

    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Wheat, new Rectangle(11 - xx, 22 - yy, 22, 311));
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.RosyBrown, new Rectangle(11 - xx, 280 - yy, 22, 3));
}

private void panel1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Invalidate();
}
```

I have added an `Invalidate` to the `Scroll` event to avoid messed up painting results.

- The other option is simpler: Make your control large enough to hold all your drawn controls and the put it **inside** a `Panel` with `AutoScroll=true;` this will delegate the whole scrolling business to the containing Panel.

Answer (score -1):

you can use a`Panel` with `AutoScroll = true`. After that, if you put any controls inside it, as long as their size is larger than the size of panel, the panel will automatically show scroll bars.. The trick can be used for any custom control asa well, as long as you place it inside a AutoScroll panel, and size it as large as you need it to be.

Answer (score -1):

I've partially solved this problem by creating a custom control that inherits from Control and that is completely drawn in OnPaint.  My solution so far is to use ScrollBarRenderer to draw my scroll buttons, then I define a Rectangle for the scrollable area.  I then create an Image to draw my scrollable content onto, and use TranslateTransform Scroll that Image into position before using DrawImage to draw into the Scrollable Content Rectangle that I created.  It's showing promise, although I haven't gotten it completely working yet since I have to handle all of the MouseOver and Click events on my own.